# mysql query sort database

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

Hello I have a table with 4 column in the column 4 the value come from a list box already pre establish by me , let say column 4 is populate by value a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j.

presently I can sort them in alpha order and get that on a PHP page .

I will like to be able to get on a page just d,e and f 
how can I achieve that

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn4 IN ('d','e','f')`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
SELECT column4 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE column4 IN ('d','e','f') 
ORDER BY column4 ASC;
```

or if you know you want the elents with letters "bigger" than 'd' but don't know how many they are, you can do:

```
SELECT column4 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE column4 >= 'd'
ORDER BY column4 ASC;
```